# Run a command before shutdown on raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, retropie

so i am making a retropi arcade cabinet and i configured the tv tu turn on via hdmi-cec and using
`echo 'on 0.0.0.0' | cec-client -s -d 1` on `/etc/rc.local` and it works fine, everty time i turn on the RPI4 the tv turns on automaticaly, im trying to use `echo 'standby 0.0.0.0' | cec-client -s -d 1` to turn it of(put it  in standby) is there a similar place like `/etc/rc.local` that will run the command right before shuting down or rebooting the RPI$????

Answer (score 2):

I'd stop using `/etc/rc.local` altogether, it's old school sysVinit

try creating a systemd service - for example run the following

```
sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/mytv.service << EOF
[Unit]
Description=Control TV
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target
After=basic.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo 'on 0.0.0.0' | cec-client -s -d 1"
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "echo 'standby 0.0.0.0' | cec-client -s -d 1"
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
```

Then you can

```
sudo systemctl enable mytv
sudo systemctl start mytv
```